# How to Improve Performance and speed

Tags: database, performance, connection, jython

I have written this program for connecting and fetching the data into file, but this program is so slow in fetching . is there is any way to improve the performance and faster way to load the data into the file . iam targeting around 100,000 to million of records so thats why iam worried about performance and also can i use array fetch size and batch size as we can do in java.

```
import java.sql as sql
import java.lang as lang
def main():
    driver, url, user, passwd = ('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe','odi_temp','odi_temp')
    ##### Register Driver
    lang.Class.forName(driver)
    ##### Create a Connection Object
    myCon = sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd)
    f = open('c:/test_porgram.txt', 'w')
    try:
        ##### Create a Statement
        myStmt = myCon.createStatement()
        ##### Run a Select Query and get a Result Set
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select emp_id ,first_name,last_name,date_of_join from src_sales_12")
        ##### Loop over the Result Set and print the result in a file
        while (myRs.next()):
            print >> f , "%s,%s,%s,%s" %(myRs.getString("EMP_ID"),myRs.getString("FIRST_NAME"),myRs.getString("LAST_NAME"),myRs.getString("DATE_OF_JOIN") )
    finally:
        myCon.close()
        f.close()

### Entry Point of the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It would help a lot to know how slow (per record) and what hardware you're working with. Need to find your bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're on the finest, finest gear for the DB and file server, or the worst gear running the script, this application is I/O bound. After the select has returned from the DB, the actual movement of the data will dominate more than any inefficiencies in Jython, Java, or this code.

You CPU is basically unconscious during this process, you're simply not doing enough data transformation. You could write a process that is slower than the I/O, but this isn't one of them.

You could write this in C and I doubt you'd see a substantial difference.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the Oracle command-line SQL client to directly export the results of that query into a CSV file?

Comment: well iam trying to make a universal program so that ican change the database connection and driver and still it work for any database.

Comment: In other words, "write once, run everywhere, just very slowly".

Comment: @APC: Well Jython *is* Python on top of Java.

Answer (score 0):

You might use getString with hardcoded indices instead of the column name (in your print statement) so the program doesn't have to look up the names over and over. Also, I don't know enough about Jython/Python file output to say whether this is enabled by default or not, but you should try to make sure your output is buffered.

EDIT:

Code requested (I make no claims about the correctness of this code):

```
print >> f , "%s,%s,%s,%s" %(myRs.getString(0),myRs.getString(1),myRs.getString(2),myRs.getString(3) )
```

or

```
myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select emp_id ,first_name,last_name,date_of_join from src_sales_12")
hasFirst = myRs.next()
if (hasFirst):
    empIdIdx = myRs.findColumn("EMP_ID")
    fNameIdx = myRs.findColumn("FIRST_NAME")
    lNameIdx = myRs.findColumn("LAST_NAME")
    dojIdx = myRs.findColumn("DATE_OF_JOIN")
    print >> f , "%s,%s,%s,%s" %(myRs.getString(empIdIdx),myRs.getString(fNameIdx),myRs.getString(lNameIdx),myRs.getString(dojIdx) )
    ##### Loop over the Result Set and print the result in a file
    while (myRs.next()):
        print >> f , "%s,%s,%s,%s" %(myRs.getString(empIdIdx),myRs.getString(fNameIdx),myRs.getString(lNameIdx),myRs.getString(dojIdx) )
```

Comment: can you please show me an example about how to getstring with hardcoded indices.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your help

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to fetch data into files ,you can try database tools(for example , "load","export").

Answer (score 0):

You may also find that if you do the construction of the string which goes into the file in the SQL select statement, you will get better performance.

So your SQL select should be SELECT EMP_ID || ','  || FIRST_NAME || ','  || LAST_NAME || ',' || DATE_OF_JOIN MY_DATA ... (depending on what database and separator is)

then in your java code you just get the one string empData = myRs.findColumn("EMP_DATA") and write that to a file.  We have seen significant performance benefits doing this.

The other thing you may see benefit from is changing the JDBC connection to use a larger read buffer - rather than 30 rows at a time in the fetch, fetch 5000 rows.